# Update related entities data during adding data for an entity in EF Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have two entities `Payroll` and `Entries` which have one to many relationship. Multiple entries can be associated to a payroll. Basically, during the newly payroll creation, entries needs to be associated with the `PayrollId` and for that I have wrote the below mentioned code to achieve the whole changes in single `SaveChanges()`.

`Payroll` entity:

```
public class Payroll : BaseEntity, ITrackCreated, ITrackUpdated
{
    public int PayrollId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PayrollStatus Status { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public List<Entries> Entries {get;set;}
}
```

`Entries` entity:

```
public class Entries : BaseEntity, ITrackCreated, ITrackUpdated
{
   public int EntryId { get; set; }
   public EntryType EntryType { get; set; }
   public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
   public Decimal Amount { get; set; }
   public EntryStatus Status { get; set; }
   public int? PayrollId { get; set; }
   public virtual Payroll Payroll {get;set;}
}
```

Entities relation:

```
public EntriesConfiguration(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) : base(modelBuilder)
{
    base.Configure();
    Builder.HasKey(t => t.EntryId);
    Builder.Property(p => p.EntryId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    Builder.HasOne(x => x.Payroll).WithMany(x => x.Entries).HasForeignKey(x => x.PayrollId);
    Builder.ToTable("Entries");
}
```

Code for the payroll creation and `payrollId` update to entries:

```
foreach (var entryGroup in groups)
{
   var creditEntries = await _commonDbFunction.GetCreditEntries(entryGroup, EntryStatus.Pending);
   var debitEntries = await _commonDbFunction.GetDebitEntries(entryGroup, EntryStatus.Pending);
   exceptionPayrollDetail = CreatePayroll(payrollDetail); 
   // binding data in payroll entity model

   await _applicationDbContext.Payrolls.AddAsync(exceptionPayrollDetail);

   creditEntries?.ForEach(x => x.PayrollId = exceptionPayrollDetail?.PayrollId); 
   //updating payrollId of above model in Entries Table

   debitEntries?.ForEach(x => x.PayrollId = exceptionPayrollDetail?.PayrollId);
   //updating payrollId of above model in Entries Table

   await _applicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync(); 
   // calling single SaveChanges adding payroll and updating enries.
}
```

Please suggest the way to achieve the same in single `SaveChanges()` as 0 `PayrollId` is not allowing to save the data in `Entries` table also `payrollId` should be greater than zero while updating in entries.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: As far as i remember - you can just `.forEach(x => x.Payroll = exceptionPayrollDetail)`. Even when Payroll is not yet in db and id for it is not yet generated - it will be picked up.

Answer (score 1):

since the `exceptionPayrollDetail` is not yet persisted to the db, the `exceptionPayrollDetail?.PayrollId` will always be zero.

may be you can call `SaveChangesAsync()`  after `await _applicationDbContext.Payrolls.AddAsync(exceptionPayrollDetail);`, then this would have the `PayrollId` generated

Comment: Thanks for your response but We need to Add and Update the entities in single `SaveChanges()`

Comment: then as for your code, you can wrap it using a database transaction object and then do the SaveChangesAsync() after await _applicationDbContext.Payrolls.AddAsync(exceptionPayrollDetail); and then update the  creditEntries and finally do the transaction.Commit(). hope this will help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions

Comment: @thanjeel We have already implemented the transaction but looking for some other way around. Is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: i think you did not get my point. if you wrap entire code in a transaction object, the code will note be committed unless you call transaction.commit(), but you will have the Payroll ids which will not be zero in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can set the navigation property itself, not the id, if you need.

Slightly simplified example:

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Entries> Entries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Payroll> Payrolls { get; set; }
    public string DbPath { get; }

    public ApplicationContext()
    {
        DbPath = System.IO.Path.Join(@"D:\Work\Envisability\EFCorePlayground\EFCorePlayground", "blogging.db");
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseSqlite($"Data Source={DbPath}");
        //options.LogTo(Console.WriteLine);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var entriesBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity<Entries>();
        entriesBuilder.Property(p => p.EntryId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        entriesBuilder.HasOne(x => x.Payroll).WithMany(x => x.Entries).HasForeignKey(x => x.PayrollId);
        entriesBuilder.HasKey(t => t.EntryId);
        entriesBuilder.ToTable("Entries");
    }

    public void Seed()
    {
        if (Entries.Any() || Payrolls.Any()) return;

        var entries = new List<Entries>
        {
            new Entries{ Name="e1" },
            new Entries{ Name="e2" },
            new Entries{ Name="e3" }
        };
        var payrolls = new List<Payroll>
        {
            new Payroll{ Name = "1" },
            new Payroll{ Name = "2" },
        };

        entries[0].Payroll = payrolls[0];
        entries[1].Payroll = payrolls[0];
        entries[2].Payroll = payrolls[1];

        Payrolls.AddRange(payrolls);
        Entries.AddRange(entries);
        SaveChanges();
    }

}

public class Payroll
{
    public int PayrollId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Entries> Entries { get; set; }
}

public class Entries
{
    public int EntryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? PayrollId { get; set; }
    public virtual Payroll Payroll { get; set; }
}
```

Take a look at the Seed method above, no ids there due to database is fresh and empty.

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var _dbContext = new ApplicationContext())
        {
            _dbContext.Seed();

            var entries = _dbContext.Entries
                .Select(x => new {Id = x.EntryId, Name = x.Name, PayrollId = x.PayrollId})
                .ToList();
            var payrolls = _dbContext.Payrolls
                .Select(x => new {Id = x.PayrollId, Name = x.Name})
                .ToList();
            Debug.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(entries));
            Debug.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(payrolls));
        }
    }
}
```

Output will be

```
[
  {"Id":1,"Name":"e1","PayrollId":1},
  {"Id":2,"Name":"e2","PayrollId":1},
  {"Id":3,"Name":"e3","PayrollId":2}
]
[
  {"Id":1,"Name":"1"},{"Id":2,"Name":"2"}
]
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data#adding-a-related-entity